# How to filter on more than one field with tuple using "in" combinator (<-.)

Tags: haskell, persistent

[Documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.13.2.1/docs/Database-Persist.html#v:-60--45-.) explains how to use "in" combinator (`<-.`) for one field:

```
selectSPJ :: MonadIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m [Entity User]
selectSPJ = selectList [UserAge <-. [40]] []
```

Is there a way to use it with more than one field? Like:

```
selectUsers :: MonadIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m [Entity User]
selectUsers = selectList [(UserName, UserAge) <-. [("SPJ", 40), ("John Doe", 30]] []
```

Which would translate to:

```sql
select user.name, user.age from user 
where (name, age) in (values ('SPJ', 40), ('John Doe', 30));
```

Combinator' signature relies on `PersistField`:

```
(<-.) :: forall v typ. PersistField typ => EntityField v typ -> [typ] -> Filter v
```

But I can't see a way to sneak in a tuple:

```
data EntityField record :: Type -> Type
```

I managed to do it with "and" (`[Filter record]`) and "or" (`||.`) combinators

```
mkFilters namesAndAges = foldl' mkFilter [] namesAndAges
mkFilter filters (name, age) = [UserName ==. name, UserAge ==. age] ||. filters
```

But the resulting query is much slower:

```sql
select user.name, user.age from user 
where (name = 'SPJ' and age = 40) or (name = 'John Doe' and age = 30);
```

Comment: I see an instance `(PersistField a, PersistField b) => PersistField (a, b)` exists. What error do you get if you try the using the tuple? (Note that you also have a syntax error in the tuple code you posted.)

Comment: Yes, a typo: I adapted existing code to fit doc.
I noted this instance too but didn't find a way to make one.

Comment: Adapted to the doc example, it would be:
`Couldn't match expected type ‘EntityField  User (String, Int)’  
with actual type ‘(EntityField User String, EntityField User Int)’`